# Recaptcha not responsive in small resolution devices

Tags: css, recaptcha

I have added Recaptcha to a form and it is not responsive in smaller resolution devices. I couldn't find a solution to this. Please help. 
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: https://geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/

Comment: Thanks. Its working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me to make recaptcha responsive.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="light" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" style="transform:scale(0.77);-webkit-transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;"></div>
```